# Para que serve o atributo prefix no elemento (tag) html?

Tags: html5, xml, semântica

Porque usa-se o atributo prefix em elementos (tag) html? E no HTML5, posso também utilizar? Obrigada!

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O atributo `prefix` é **um** dos atributos criados pelo [RDFa (*Resource Description Framework in Attributes*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa).

**RDFa** é uma extensão, a nível de atributo, para diversas linguagens de marcação, como HTML e XML. Essa extensão foi criada para suportar [Web Semântica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_sem%C3%A2ntica) em páginas web. Ao invés de você ter uma página web (definida por um arquivo `.html` ou `.xml`) que informa ao navegador apenas como a página dever ser estruturada, o **RDFa** permite também inserir **informações sobre o que a sua página web representa**, por exemplo: listagem de produtos, página de criação de uma cidade, etc.

Nesse contexto, o atributo `prefix` é utilizado para que você possa definir um **vocabulário semântico** que será utilizado na sua página web. Um **vocabulário semântico** é uma definição de estruturas que serão utilizadas e representadas nas páginas web, muito similar a estruturas de dados em algoritmos. Você poder ter, por exemplo, um vocabulário que define a estrutura padrão que representa uma Pessoa. Um **vocabulário semântico** bastante popular é o [schema.org](http://schema.org/).

Mas nem sempre apenas um vocabulário é o suficiente para descrever toda a semântica de sua página web. Por isso o atributo `prefix` foi criado. Utilizando ele você pode ter mais de um vocabulário em sua página. Abaixo eu utilizo dois vocabulários para descrever **uma Pessoa** que possui **um Animal de estimação preferido**: [schema.org](http://schema.org/) e [vocab.org](http://vocab.org/open/).

```
<p vocab="http://schema.org/" prefix="ov: http://open.vocab.org/terms/" resource="#manu" typeof="Person">
    Meu nome é <span property="name">MEU_NOME</span>

    e meu telefone é <span property="telephone">MEU_TELEFONE</span>.

    Meu animal de estimação preferido é <span property="ov:preferredAnimal">ANIMAL_ESTIMAÇÃO</span>.
</p>
```

Como pode ser visto no exemplo acima, você pode utilizar o atributo `prefix` em qualquer tag HTML (e XML também), e não apenas `<html>`.

**Respondendo sua segunda pergunta:**

> E no HTML5, posso também utilizar?

Sim, é possível utilizar `prefix` em HTML5. Vendo a página oficial do padrão [**RDFa**](https://rdfa.info/), o atributo `prefix` também pode ser utilizado em XML, HTML4, XHTML1 e XHTML5, entre outros formatos.

---

**Referências** para quem quiser se aprofundar no assunto:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-rdfalite/

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-rdfa/

https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/#prefix

https://rdfa.info/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_sem%C3%A2ntica